# "Include" instead of ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a WindowsFormApplication in Visual Studio 2015 and need some help.
I've been trying to search for the answer on internet but can find out how to do the following:

I have two windows (solutions?). I open the second window with a button in the first one with this code:

```
this.Hide();
intermec prodinter = new intermec();
prodinter.ShowDialog();
```

My question is:
How can i "include" the second window (like "include" in PHP) instead of close the first window and then open the next one, like it does now?

Comment: You have two forms, you wish to open the second one? you dont have to hide the first if you dont wish to hide the first, you can just open a second, unlike php for web pages when realistically its one page at a time, you can have twenty forms open if you wish. What have you tried?

Comment: Explain it a little more. What do you mean by "include" the window?

Comment: No, i kind of want to hide it. Lets us PHP web page as an example: In PHP i can have an index.php file that I have all the main "things" on my page. And than I can include things to that page with for excample a button. I want to do the same thing in C# and WindowFormApplication.

Comment: @NickiJey I believe what you want is called a 'custom' user control... read this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/user-control-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Your question is very generic. You may have a look at [User controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) or maybe [MDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx). But if you explain more what do you exactly have in mind, we could help more

Answer (score 1):

A Form is just another Control. Think of it as a Container (because it holds other Controls).

A User Control can also hold more than one Control. There are ways you can display a Window inside another Window in a WinForms app, but the desired effect is not always guaranteed. So it would be best to place all of your controls (for "page 1", for example) in a User Control called "Page1", and then, when appropriate, add that User Control to the Form, and set its Dock property to Fill.

And when it's time to show a different "page", `Hide();` "Page1", and `Show();` "Page2".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about form inheritance:

Just create a form, lets call it as frmBase. And add some controls onto frmBase which you want to have on other forms as well.

Create other form, lets call it as frmDerived.

In the code behind of frmDerived, just do the following:

```
// derive the frmDerived form from frmBase
public partial class frmDerived : frmBase
{
    public frmDerived()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And then just check the frmDerived form design, it should include everything from frmBase.

And you may want to make the access modifier of some controls of frmBase to Public as required to access them on frmDerived.

I hope this will help you. :)